# prevent xmlHttpReq 's browser caching

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

It seems that all the browsers other than Opera cache XHR requests in my Javascript program.
The URL in the XHR request refers to a CGI program on the server which generates a different output everytime its called. B
Is there a way in Javascript to make the browser not cache XHR requests?

Answer (score 12):

For every AJAX request you make, generate a unique value and add it to the ajax URL as a query parameter:

```
/example/url/post.php?rand=09809807896768
```

I use to generate the current unix timestamp in JS and use that - this ensures I do not get duplicated stamps.

That way every request is unique and will not get cached. This is a simple but fairly common AJAX trick - usually fixing IE and testing issues.

If you were to use jQuery, it does this for you by setting the property cache to false on the [AJAX settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: I get an error trying to implement your solution: `request header field pragma is not allowed by "access-control-allow-headers"`. Any idea how to avoid this? Look:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23048184/xmlhttprequest-with-no-cache-request-header-is-not-allowed

Comment: @LuisA.Florit Not only do I see no response to your comment (which could be a question of its own) but the link you posted doesn't even work.  An extraordinary shame since I'm having the same problem. :(