# jQuery $.post() function not working in IE unless developer tools is open

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, callback

The jQuery $.post() function is not working in IE. I tried to open developer tools to see if I was getting a console error, but miraculously the function started working.

It is just a standard $.post() function

```
$.post('child_cb.php?type=check', { value: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        if (data == 'true') {
                            $(".check_case").removeClass('bad').addClass('good');
                        }
                        else if (data == 'false') {
                            $(".check_case").removeClass('good').addClass('bad');
                        }
                    });
```

I see no reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: are you sure it is not working without developer tools? I wouldn't really trust anything IE. If you want to verify AJAX calls it is best to stick with Fiddler. It will show you what is really going on.

Comment: Well, what's the error/symptom(s)? -1 for "it's not working".

Comment: And why the down votes? Seriously...

Comment: To down voter: really!?!? it is as good a question as any, and asked as well as it can be if you don't know what is going on with the logger.

Comment: This totally fixed my issue.  +1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

remove/comment out the `console.log(data)`, IE cannot process this, it should work fine after you remove this. Had this problem myself recently.

Comment: OMG, after hours of searching... you saved me. +1

Answer (score 1):

You should make a habit of using this for debugging so you don't forget the console.log :

```
if(!('console' in window) || ( ('console' in window) && !('log' in console) )){  
    window.console = {  
        log:function(e){  
            alert("You are using console log without the console!")  
        }  
    }  
}
```

you can remove the alert, but is ok if you want to be notified that you forgot something. :)