# Difficulty to remove exception in project

Tags: hibernate, gwt

I am creating application using GWT + Hibernate.I am facing out a problem; it is "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.Logger.isTraceEnabled()Z" Exception. I checked and really this method is not available in jar file. I searched for jar on net but could not find. Please help me for finding the appropriate jar.
Thnaks
Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use SL4J in your GWT client code that is not possible as it is a third party library and GWT cannot use it without translating the source code.

For logging in your client code, [please read this GWT documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging). You can also use the [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) project.

I've answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247424/how-to-print-to-the-console-in-gwt/9247784#9247784) before as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's obviously the Logger class of SLF4J, download @http://www.slf4j.org/download.html