# GWT.log logs not showing in the GWT Dev Mode console

Tags: java, gwt

I have a GWT application which is run with maven:

```
mvn gwt:run
```

However, all the `GWT.log` logs are not being showed what could be the problem?

Comment: probably the log level. Did you try `Log.warn("")` or `Log.error("")`?

Comment: @adenoyelle Can you clarify you comment, i'm using GWT.log("message"); I think you are referring to server side logging, I need client side logging

Comment: I am talking about client-side logging but with library `gwt-log` which allows to log with different log levels. I actually did not see that you were logging with GWT.log, sorry. As far as I know about GWT.log, those logs are only visible in dev mode. `gwt-log` will probably meet your need. Take a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/

Comment: @xybrek Are you sure you're running the app in DevMode in the browser? (new tab in DevMode window for the connected browser) Also, to be sure, are you saying that _none_ of the `GWT.log()` calls appear, or that _not all_ (i.e. some) are logged?

Comment: Can you share your log and handler configuration of your xml module file? usually looks like this: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Configuring_GWT_Logging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for the logging to work you need to have the following:

Logging module inherited in your module xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging" />
```

Logging [level](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html) set and [handlers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/util/logging/overview.html#1.5) configured:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINE" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

You may need a different handler configuration than this one based on what you are tring to achieve, for more info check the [offical doc on that matter](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Different_Types_of_Handlers).

Notice that the level I set up is **FINE** which would ensure that most of what you log is not ignored by any handler since FINE is one of the lowest levels. By default loggers are configured to handle only **SEVERE** level logs, which usually ignores the rest, SEVERE being the highest level.

Next you need to ensure that the level you use to log is included withing the LEVEL you setup on the XML module file. For instance if you use...

```
static final Logger logger= Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
logger.fine("--MESSAGE--");
// or     
logger.log(Level.FINE, "--MESSAGE--");
```

...the level must be set to FINE or any other level below for this messages you appear in your log, if you choose any level above FINE, all those messages will be ignored.

Hope this helps...

Comment: For your Logger class, do you import java.util.logging.Logger?