# IEs developer tools causes behavior to change

Tags: css, internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

When I view my page in IE10 w/compat. mode (IE7 Standards) the page renders certain elements incorrectly. However, when I go to inspect the elements with Developer Tools (F12) and change *anything*, all of a sudden, the elements are rendered correctly.

Anyone ever seen anything like this before? If so, how did you fix it? It is maddening trying to troubleshoot, while not being able to touch anything.

Comment: IE10 is still in Beta, I wouldn't be relying on anything it does for testing sites.

Comment: I noticed something along the lines of "console.log()" working when the Dev Tools were open, but throwing an exception when they weren't :(

Comment: Could it be the same issue as this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/ie9-bug-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-once-very-stran/7742862#7742862

Comment: @RickCalder - Nope, this is IE10 RTM (on Windows 8)

Comment: @Spudley No console.log functions on the page, that was the first thing I thought of as well, but this is CSS not being applied properly (and none of it is generated by JavaScript)

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here, IE10 dev. tools make certain CSS styles completely dissapear!
I noticed that with class-name "top" loosing its definition.
Funny is when I renamed it to class="topbar" my problem was solved.