# Java Script Not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, checkbox, console.log

created a checkbox features with jQuery for a website, The features are working fine with all other browsers like Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera etc.. But it is not working in IE all version. Here is my code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <ul id="filters" style="list-style:none; margin-top:75px; line-height:30px; ">

    <li>

        <input type="checkbox" value="outdoor" id="outdoor" />

        <label for="filter-category">Outdoor</label>

    </li>

    <li>

        <input type="checkbox" value="remote_monitor" id="remote_monitor" />

        <label for="filter-category">Remote Monitor</label>

    </li>


     <li>

        <input type="checkbox" value="battery" id="battery" />

        <label for="filter-category">Battery Operated</label>

    </li>

</ul>
<div style="width:850px; height:148px; clear:both; margin-top:80px;">

<div  class="category outdoor " style=" float:left;  ">Rocco</div>

<div  class="category remote_monitor camera" style="float:left;margin-top:-2px; margin-left:10px;">Borocco</div>

<div  class="category battery" style="float:left; margin-top:-2px;margin-left:10px;">Sylva</div>

<div  class="category battery outdoor " style="float:left; margin-top:-2px;margin-left:10px;">Novesto</div>

<script>
$('input').change (function() {

        var selector = $('input:checkbox').map(function(){ 

            return this.checked ? '.' + this.id : ''; 


        }).get().join('');


        console.log(selector);  



        var all = $('div[class^="category"]');

        if(selector.length)

          all.hide().filter(selector).show()

        else all.hide();

    });
</script>
```

Anyone can help please!

Comment: I see you've tagged the question `console.log`... could it be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once/7742862#7742862

Comment: What @Spudley linked. IE doesn't know what `console` is unless the dev tools are open.

Comment: May be this can be tried ? `if(typeof console !== 'undefined') console.log(selector)`

Comment: @Jashwant The question Spudley linked to contains shims to console.log.

Comment: Thanks I just removed console.log(selector); Now it works well in IE and all other browsers. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` doesn't work in IE until the Dev Tools window is opened.

The short answer to this is simply don't use `console.log()` in your code unless you are actively testing. If you are testing, you will have Dev Tools open anyway, so the code will work. If you're not testing, remove the `console.log()`; it serves no purpose.

A more detailed answer can be found here: [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once/7742862#7742862)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in internet explorer. I believe, like already pointed out in the comments - that you do not have your console open (f12) in internet explorer. You need to have the developer tools open for *console.log* to work - Or it will cause an error (and the execution of your javascript will stop)

One of the issues:

```
console.log(selector);
```

[**Your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/78UzX/)

Comment: Absolutely right. It is all because of the console.log, so I just removed it. Working Fine in IE. Thank you very much.