# Jquery Validation plugin in IE 9 on initial load of Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, internet-explorer

Currently using Jquery v1.9.0 and jquery validation plugin v1.10.0. we have simple form with two text box and a submit button. On click of submit button text in input elements are validated and a javascript function is called.

This functionality works fine in all the browser but when we load the website in IE 9 , form submit will  redirect to the Action URL specified in the form tag but validation does not work and if we invoke the developer tools and refresh the page Validation plugin works fine.

when we open the developer tool browser mode is IE Compat View and document mode is IE 9 Standard.

How do we ensure Validation plugin work on initial load without opening developer tools and website refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the fix for this issue it is because of console.log function usage. Click the link for more details

[JQuery not working in IE 9.0.8, but works with dev tools open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677268/jquery-not-working-in-ie-9-0-8-but-works-with-dev-tools-open)