# website not working ok in IE8, 9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, console, internet-explorer-9

I made website http://www.kuha.si and it's working fine in new browsers (IE10, Firefox 20, Chrome and Safari) but there are problems in IE 8 and 9 and firefox 3.6

Problem is on home page on top of the page where I present dishes with coresponding dates. 
In older browser this is shown empty. Main probles is that if I hit F12 to get console to examine, everything starts working (both in IE and FF) and there are shown no errors so I can't figure out the problem.

Problematic menu is made like this, that I pull content with PHP from database and then rearrange it with javascript to show it in slider.

Do you have idea what is wrong and why is everthing start working when I hit f12 and refresh site?

Comment: Don't use `console.log` (`console.log(jedilnikSkupaj);` line 283 in generated page) or use something like that: `if(window.console && window.console.log) { console.log(jedilnikSkupaj); }`. This might be the problem for IE browser.

Comment: Yupi, I removed console.log and it works. Why is console.log problem isn't it just for info.

Comment: I found out where problems is on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once Never fought console.log could be problem. @Xeon thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting it here as it resolved problem:

Don't use `console.log` (`console.log(jedilnikSkupaj);` line 283 in generated page) or use something like that:

```
if(window.console && window.console.log) { 
    console.log(jedilnikSkupaj); 
}
```

This might be the problem for IE browsers.