# Links will not work until browser resize event with history.js

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, compatibility, history.js

I am having this very strange issues and I really need help getting is resolved as it's on a client site and they are hammering me about it.

This seemed to be working before but now all of a sudden we are having issues with it.

The site is at

www.chosenwomensconference.com

And the problem happens in IE9.

What is happening is when you try to click on a link at the bottom nothing happens, you can try to refresh over and over and even resize the browser a few times and refresh some more but nothing works. It's only when you open up the f12 developer console and close it again that when you refresh the site starts working just fine. And we can't figure out why.

It is also to be noted that running the browser in compatibility mode seems to work each time without having to open the console first. But all my efforts to get the browser to force computability mode are not working.

I'm really hoping someone can take a look and help me determine what seems to be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your answer might be here: [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

The code that you have to debug the link being clicked (in `main.js` I think) is causing an error in IE unless `console` is defined.

Comment: This fixed it thank you, I have never heard of this, I'll have to keep this  in mind, I'm not sure why it was in there I must have missed it.