# Internet Explorer Javascript not running from event issue

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to get an function to run from an event listener on a form submit.

Chrome & Firefox (Iceweasel) work fine with this code. Internet explorer (Version 9) for some reason requires me to open up the developer tools and close it down straight away for the javascript to work, after the page can be refreshed and the code works fine.

The site is published at http://itdipext.ryanteck.org.uk/enquire.html and the javascript is at http://itdipext.ryanteck.org.uk/javascriptValidate.js

**Why Internet Explorer 8?, Heck why javascript for basic form validation?**
This is for a college assignment where HTML5 does not even exist yet. And internet explorer to make the teacher happy.

Thanks -
Ryan Walmsley

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Its in the link of the javascript. Its 100+ Lines of code. Its not really the code its the browser!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its due to the heavy use of `console.log` in your script.

IE doesn't create the console object until dev tools is open. You can add this to the top of your script to stop it breaking

```
var console=console||{"log":function(){}};
```

Be aware it wont log anything to the console with this in place.