# Routing not working until open developer tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to work angular with ie8, and a curious thing happens to me ..

The routing does not work until I open the developers tool.

I do not do anything, just open the developer tools in IE8 and links begin to function properly.

If you do not open when I click the link nothing happens.

Here the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="acmeApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
    <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
....

<ul>
   <li><a ng-click="goToAcme()" href="javascript:void(0)">foo</a></li>
   <li><a ng-click="goToAcme2()" href="javascript:void(0)">bar</a></li>
   <li><a ng-click="goToAcme3()" href="javascript:void(0)">foobar</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: you may have a console.log in your code.

Comment: Might be pertinent to your case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once