# Mesh Detection works only after I have opened Console

Tags: javascript, three.js, developer-tools, console.log, raycasting

I write an app with three.js, where I want to **detect** some circles when the **mouse clicks on them**. 
The problem is that it works great only if I opened (and then close it or not, doesn't matter) the Chrome developer tools! If I don't it detects the clicking on the circle very difficultly (one at 5 times)!

I read this [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

and I erased my **console calls** (even though I don't run it on IE). Although, in the three.js file that I downloaded there are many many console calls but I don't think this is the problem.

What can I do?!

CODE to crate circles:

```
for (var i = 0; i <6; i++) {

                        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {

                              var crcl = {};


                                crcl.obj = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CircleGeometry( 1.7, 30, 0, Math.PI * 2 ), mat);
                                crcl.obj.position.set(j*4.5+7, 277-i*3, 250);
                                crcl.obj.scale.set(1,1,1);

                                scene.add(crcl.obj);
                                SlotsToDetect.push(crcl.obj); // array to help detect click 
                                PlayingSlotMatrix[i][j]=crcl; // array that hold circles for future handling

                              }
 }
```

CODE to find the circle:

```
var intersectsSLOTS = raycaster.intersectObjects(SlotsToDetect, true); 
 if(intersectsSLOTS.length>0 ){

               clickedObject=intersectsSLOTS[0].object; 
               updateSlots(clickedObject.id);

  }
```

**EDIT: I want to add that sometimes I get the error "Cannot read property 'getDescendants' of undefined " for the var intersectDescendants = function ( object, raycaster, intersects ) {..} function in the Three.js file.**

EDIT 2: Chrome does not show alert() anymore at all. Though, it shows the console calls. what does that mean?

Comment: can we see your code please