# Javascript only running on open/close developer mode - IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I thought I may have found the solution under this post:

[Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

But my problem is I have to close/open developer mode to get the js functions running. The function will not run when I just have the developer mode open. Rather, it waits until I clicked open/close developer mode window, then it will run.

It seems to hold the function in a queue and runs it after I have opened/closed developer mode.

Any possible idea of what is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

EDIT:
The specific function call has the 2 lines below:

```
parent.document.getElementById('frameset_id').cols = '60%, *'
parent.window.frame_id.location.href='asp_file.asp?passID=' + ID
```

Again, the code will run when I open/close developer mode, so I do not believe it is a syntax error. I may need to explore alternatives to adjusting the cols size and assigning the frame location.

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't show your code

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have `console.log` somewhere in your code. `console` does not exist at all in IE when the dev tools are closed, and it silently stops your JS from running.

Comment: The OP already says that they have to close dev tools for it to work, not open it.

Comment: Oh, oops... then maybe he has a debugging breakpoint that he doesn't realize is there.