# IE11 truncates string in console

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, console.log

I have a string of maybe 20 or 30 lines i'd like to output to the console all in one console.log call. This works great in Chrome, but IE11 truncates about half of the string in the console. Any way to prevent this? The string is something like:

```
-----------------------------------------
Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
-----------------------------------------
41:17:181 - Initiating recording...
41:17:233 - Creating NetStream...
41:17:240 - NetStream created.
41:17:240 - Recording ready.
-----------------------------------------
Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 NetConnectionQueue - rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
-----------------------------------------
41:16:867 - Initializing...
41:16:868 - Creating negotiator...
41:17:175 - Connection success: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:175 - Connection added to queue.
41:17:182 - Connection request recieved...
41:17:183 - Connection request fulfilled.
41:17:452 - Connection success: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:452 - Connection added to queue.
41:18:503 - -----------------------------------------
Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 NetNegotiator Log
-----------------------------------------
41:16:890 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:174 - Negotiator reset
41:17:194 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:282 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:443/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:339 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:80/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:400 - Attempting: rtmpt://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:451 - NetConnection attempt failed: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:443/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9
41:17:452 - Negotiator reset
```

Comment: The problem is this is a log coming from inside a swf i'm working on. For now my work around is:

`var index:int = 0, buffer:int = 1024;
var log:String = _logger.log + (_playbackConnectionQueue ? _playbackConnectionQueue.log : '') + _recorderConnectionQueue.log;
while ( index < log.length) {
 ExternalInterface.call("console.error", log.substr(index, index + buffer));
 index += buffer;
}`

Comment: Btw, i dont think this is an ExternalInterface thing. I can get the whole log out of the swf fine, and then a normal console.log/error from js results in the same truncation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A 1024 character limit on a single message isn't exactly unreasonable. Even if it was, IE offers no means of altering that limitation.

Out of curiosity, why is this one big block rather than individual calls to `console.log()` grouped with `console.group()`?

```js
console.group("Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:181 - Initiating recording...");
console.log("41:17:233 - Creating NetStream...");
console.log("41:17:240 - NetStream created.");
console.log("41:17:240 - Recording ready.");
console.groupEnd();
console.group("Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 NetConnectionQueue - rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:16:867 - Initializing...");
console.log("41:16:868 - Creating negotiator...");
console.log("41:17:175 - Connection success: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:175 - Connection added to queue.");
console.log("41:17:182 - Connection request recieved...");
console.log("41:17:183 - Connection request fulfilled.");
console.log("41:17:452 - Connection success: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:452 - Connection added to queue.");
console.groupEnd();
console.group("Wed Jan 7 20:41:16 GMT-0700 2015 NetNegotiator Log");
console.log("41:16:890 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:174 - Negotiator reset");
console.log("41:17:194 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:282 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:443/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:339 - Attempting: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:80/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:400 - Attempting: rtmpt://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:1935/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:451 - NetConnection attempt failed: rtmp://AMS2alt.commercialtribe.net:443/recorder/530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a5853a47a049c52c9d83a2d71d9");
console.log("41:17:452 - Negotiator reset");
console.groupEnd();
```

[image: sample console output showing multiple groups of logged statements]

If the message is received as one big string you could certainly log it in smaller slices:

```js
function processSlices(sliceable, sliceSize, callback) {
  var i = 0,
    n = sliceable.length,
    // handle string, array, and array-like
    fn = sliceable.slice || Array.prototype.slice;
  while (i < n) {
    callback(fn.call(sliceable, i, i += sliceSize));
  }
}
// small sample with sliceSize of 7
processSlices("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789", 7, console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><script>console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false})</script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block;}</style>
```

Comment: This is a great answer; the user should indeed be using `console.log` *within* `console.group` when dealing with related output. As you point out, 1024 chars should be more than enough to convey individual log messages.

Comment: Should probably not use arrow functions for IE11 examples, since that will just throw a Syntax error.

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but just posting in case this helps anyone who finds it.

If you're like me and just wanted to make sure you're getting all the right data into a string for a simple test, you could do something like this. Maybe a little complicated but was helpful when I had a long string I needed to check was formed correctly and had the right content.
You could definitely pair this with the *console.group()* mentioned in the accepted (canon's) answer too.

```js
function consoleLog(str, blockSize) {
    // blockSize is a parameter only to support the tests.
    if (blockSize === undefined) {
        blockSize = 1024;
    }
    var limit = Math.floor(str.length / blockSize);
    for (var k = 0; k < limit+1; k++) {
      if (k == limit)
          console.log(str.substring(blockSize*k, str.length));
      else
          console.log(str.substring(blockSize*k, blockSize*(k+1)));
    }
}

// Tests.

// Should print:
// aaaaa
// bbbbb
// c
consoleLog('aaaaabbbbbc', 5);

// Should print:
// aaaaa
// bbbbb
consoleLog('aaaaabbbbb', 5);
```

Comment: Nice answer - helped me debug a stupid IE issue. This function seems to drop the character in between the chunks though - "...SQL..." goes to "...S" and "L..." though.

Answer (score 2):

If the text you should log is not broken into lines, or the lines might be longer than the limit, you can use this simple function to "format" the log output:

```js
function logMessage(title, message) {
    // make sure if the 'console' object and its methods are available,
    // to avoid issues, like your JS code is broken by logging.
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7742862/704022
    if (console && console.log && console.group && console.groupEnd) {
        var maxLength = 10; // set to 10 to enable easier testing, should be 1024
        console.group(title);
        for (var pos = 0; pos < message.length ; pos += maxLength) {
            console.log(message.substring(pos, pos + maxLength));
        }
        console.groupEnd();
    }
}

logMessage("Test", "0123456789012345678901234");
```

Comment: @user3251189: I rejected your edit (fixed bug - missing parameter with groupEnd) because the groupEnd function of the console object has no parameter, AFAIK. It simply finishes the last opened group, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/groupEnd, http://docs.w3cub.com/dom/console/groupend, https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_groupend.asp
Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: pholpar: You are correct. I was seeing some inconsistent results with multiple group messages and thought the missing parameter would fix it (later found it did not). This was only occurring in IE11 and appears to be a race condition inherent to IE. If I put a 100ms delay between message logging the problem would never occur. There is a reference of groupEnd having that parameter but seems to be isolated to IE and I haven't found any scenario where using it makes a difference.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/dn265070(v=vs.80)