# Is there any maximum length limit with window.postMessage at Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, postmessage

I`m using the window.postMessage by sending some data.
The data is html element, so the size is little big.

But there was an issue on IE environment.
The data was broken with max length **1024**.

I checked the postMessage IE limitation but I couldn`t find something.

environment:

- IE 11
- iframe communication
- window.postMessage

Is there any maximum length limitation?

[image: 1024 is max length]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem with another point.
This 1024 length problem was `console.log` problem.
There was the max length of one console log message at the Internet Explorer 11. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844847/11506231)

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.