# ActiveX only working when IE 9 Console is activated

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I'm building a small web application that needs to access Powerpoint through ActiveX and Javascript (and IE9...) to automatically build a report. I'm am using ActiveX because I can't generate the Powerpoint file on the server side (although I would have prefered this very much).

My code right now is very bare boned as I'm just beginning:

```
// Creating the ActiveX Powerpoint control
var ppt;
try{
    ppt = new ActiveXObject("Powerpoint.Application");
}catch(e){
    if (e instanceof ReferenceError)
        alert("Your browser might not be compatible with this function. Please use Internet Explorer.");
    else
        alert("An error happened: " + e);
}
console.log("ActiveX Object created");

// Openning Powerpoint, make it visible
ppt.Visible = 1;

// Creating a new Presentation, and adding a blank (1 slide, 1 = ppLayoutBlank) Slide
ppt.Presentations.Add();
ppt.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 1);
```

On my computer, it happens that the ActiveX control doesn't launch Powerpoint even if I allow it to execute through the `"An ActiveX control on this page might be dangerous; Do you allow it to execute?"` (traduced straight from French).

But, if I launch the Developper Console, it magically runs. And, on another computer with IE 11, it works fine after I allowed the ActiveX control to execute.

I think my IE Security settings are right, thus I can't think of anything else that an IE glitch I'm not aware of. I'm working with IE 9.0.8112.16421 64-bit.

**How could I get this code to run nicely?** Thank you in advance!

Comment: `console.log` in IE works only if Developer console is open... if Developer Console is closed its stops the script because console is `undefined`. Try to change `console.log("ActiveX Object created");` in `try{console.log("ActiveX Object created")}catch(err){}`.

Comment: Or just change it to an `alert("ActiveX Object created");`

Comment: Wow... Well played IE, well played!
I actually briefly through of that but would never have thought this was the issue!
It works perfectly with the `try catch`, I'll stick with that then!
@Frogmouth If you might post this as answer, so I can accept it... Thank you two for the lightning-fast answer!

Comment: @ToastyMallows - Is an other way, but (I think) it's a `log` for the developer not an `alert` for user .

Comment: @Frogmouth Well basically it's just a brief "starting developement" log to check if everything is alright. I might drop it soon as I will progress on the developement. I'm just used to use `console.log` instead of `alert` when it's not directed to the user.

Comment: @Frogmouth yes, but when you're just testing an `alert` is nice to see as a good visual indicator that some breakpoint is hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remind: `console.log` in IE works only if Developer console is open.
If the Developer Console is closes it stops the script because `console` is `undefined`.

In your code, try to change:

`console.log("ActiveX Object created");`

with

`try{console.log("ActiveX Object created")}catch(err){}` or comment the line with: `//`.