# React render method failing due to checking if state data is null

Tags: javascript, null, reactjs, bootstrapping, reactjs-flux

React 0.14.0 & Vanilla Flux

**I'm simply doing a check if the user is logged in and if so I'll display their stuff, else I'll show a loading page.**

Once the user is loaded in the store a "_onChange" is triggered and "getStateFromStores" will update the user from null to an object.

```
render: function() {
   if(this.state.user !== null){
     //Stuff that will be rendered
   }
   else{
       <div>Loading...</div>
   }
```

Yet **this if statement will throw an error because this.state.user will be null** the first time it checks

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null
```

**Is there a way to do this type of checks or will I have to create a "userLoaded" boolean or something?**

Comment: code you shared looks fine, and looks completely unrelated to your error. What's `_currentElement`? What promise? Why do you think that the error is caused by `this.state.error` being null?

Comment: @wintvelt When I add in "this.state.user !== null" it fails, when I take it out i works, and it fails on that line most likely because "user" is initially null.

Comment: hmm strange.. have you looked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786154/upgrading-react-to-0-13-2-causes-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-cu)? (others have had strange errors like this apparently). Again, your statement looks fine. Even if `this.state.user` is null, then your code should not throw this error..

Comment: @wintvelt ... you were right! It should be working fine. I just made a false negative goof cause it was late last night. Very sorry but I appreciate the help soooo much!