# Form.onsubmit not working

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, console.log

I'm creating a script to check something in my code. This script runs successfully on Chrome, but it doesn't run on IE.

This is run on `onsubmit` in my form

`<form id="frm1" name="frm1" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm();"  action="save_dept_add.php">`

And this is my script (I've put it in head tag)

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function checkForm()
{
        if (!window.console) {
             console = { log: function(){} };
        }
        var e = document.getElementById("dept");
        var xtext = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        if(xtext == ""){
            console.log("no dept");
            alert("Please select your department");                 
            return false;

        }else{
            console.log(xtext);
            var q = document.getElementById("quantity");
            var check = q.value;
            console.log(check);
            if(check == ""){
                alert("Please insert a quantity");      
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;    
            }       
        }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: what version of IE are you testing with? are you aware old versions of IE (<9) doesn't have console.log. and putting the rest of your form might help to see if there is any element-id related issues

Comment: your code maybe failing in console.log since console object is not available in IE8 unless dev tools are open.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once

Comment: @DevZer0 i'm try to use develop tools in IE browser and start debug script pop-up been run , But when i'm not use debug for develop tools pop-up can't run.

Comment: see the link i posted, and the solution posted by Halayem bottom would fix your problem, but i would just get rid of that nasty alert.

Comment: console.log is not available is IE8 which is why your code use failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the top of your JavaScript file

```
if (!window.console) {
   console = { log: function(){} };
}
```

Comment: @DevZer0 the alert was for comprehension only :)

Comment: please check my edit question. now i put this code on top like that.

Comment: you can safely move that out of your function block. to the global scope.

Comment: @DevZer0 Can you explain why we must to use  console = { log: function(){} }; please ?

Comment: I'm the owner of the response, DevZer0 has only edited it :). console is not defined in IE < 10 so I had to create a valid Referance to avoid errors