# Not getting [Object File] from a File Input HTML Control using JQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, file-upload

I have a `file input control` and `button` as below:-

```
<input type="file" name="Resume" id="upload"></input>
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" onclick="sample()"></input>
```

Also a function called as `sample()`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sample(){
    var file =$('#upload')[0].files[0];
    alert(file);
    }
</script>
```

The above function is called on a click of button `btnsave`.

`Issue`:Does not return a alert with `[object File]`, inspite of file exist in file input control.

Note: I am using `I.E 11` and also loaded Jquery library.

Comment: code is correct..make sure your `file` variable is defined somewhere.

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/7b7bkyhd/

Comment: @Kartikeya: Code is modified...still issue exists..

Comment: Code is work here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfnchuon/). You should create a jsfiddle or use stack snippet that can reproduce the issue you met.

Comment: @Kartikeya yes, it works in jsfiddle but not on I.E [custom Page]...

Comment: Did you check the console, are you getting  any errors? I've just tested in *IE 11* and it works just fine.

Comment: @DavidDomain: Actually the problem does not occur when i debug or open "F12" window i.e Developers Tools, it's bit Strange infact....

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Ujwal_15/x5bgqqo7/6/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" name="Resume" id="upload" />
<input type="button" id="btnSave" value="Save" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
    var file =$('#upload')[0].files[0];
    alert(file);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing an issue in which the site you are working on is listed in your **Local Intranet** zone which causes IE to emulate an older version.  Try adding this line *as the very first entry* within your <head> tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

From Microsoft: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915.aspx