# Internet Explorer Javascript - Working Properly After Opening Inspector

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> I've reviewed similar questions without any luck: 
>   [Why Javascript Only Works After Opening Developer Tools in IE Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

Essentially, I have a page with an area that can animate a vest: [Vagalume Innovation Page](https://vagalume.ca/innovation/)

You can animate the vest with a set of options below it. In IE (all versions) it only works if you press it twice. For example, press "Slow Flash" and then "Constant" and it takes two times before it registers.

As soon as I open Developer Tools, the problem goes away.

There are no console logs to deal with, so I'm very confused. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is the code that changes the flashing pattern:

```
if ($('.demo-trigger').length) {
    $('.demo-trigger').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        clearInterval(intervalId);

        var trigger = $(this),
            pat     = trigger.data('pattern'),
            timer   = false;

        _lights.removeClass().removeAttr('class').addClass(pat);

        $('.demo-trigger').removeClass('active');
        trigger.addClass('active');         
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Seems to work as expected in ie11...

Comment: There are a few unmatched end tag errors though...

Comment: Added code snippet. For me in IE11, it only works properly after opening the dev tools once. If the dev tools aren't opened, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: I've also fixed the unmatched end tag errors, just to be sure. Behavior remains the same.