# JavaScript works only when Safari Develop Console is open

Tags: javascript, safari, telerik, developer-tools

I am using `Telerik UI controls`. They have a embedded JS, which looks like is having some dependency on `Safari 9.0.3(10601.44)` Developer console.

When we try to load telerik tree-view in telerik combo box, we get the followin error. **Only in Safari 9.0.3(10601.44)**

[image]

Same in text

```
_initRightToLeftScriptResource.axd:8396TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'c.set_additionalQueryString')
_initRightToLeftScriptResource.axd:8395
initializeScriptResource.axd:8332
endUpdateTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:49050
endCreateComponentsTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:63458
_raiseInitTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:65559
_doInitializeTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:63974
(anonymous function)Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:65784
(anonymous function)Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:50713
pTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:558
_2PassTelerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd:2:50697
```

My problem is very similar to this [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once) but in Safari.

I tried all those suggestions, none of them were helping.

**Update**

---

Code works fine with some delay in calling function.

```
 if (navigator.sayswho === "Safari 9") {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        try {
                        loadInit();
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert("error");
                            console.log(e);
                        } 
                    }, 1000);
```

tried all following, none is working, not sure how to trace the right event of full DOM is loaded and no pending ajax calls happening.

```
$(document).load(...)
$(window).load(...)
<body onload="....">
```

Comment: Just a related issue.  Same problem here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719570/undefined-error-in-plupload-dispatchevent-on-mac-safari

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Telerik controls, use:

```
Sys.Application.add_load(MyFunction);

function MyFunction(sndr, args){
//your code
}
```

This only calls the function once all the telerik controls have loaded.