# jQuery .appendTo() [IE] - Images do not render unless I resize the browser window

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I am using the jQuery functions `.render()` and `.appendTo` to render images and text on a page, specifically into a placeholder/template. It works well in Firefox and Chrome. But, in IE, the images do not render automatically. The word 'image' appears instead. If I resize the browser window (maximize, resize, or open/close Dev Tools) the images show up.

I came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-javascript-only-works-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once), because initially I only thought it happened on opening Dev Tools, but I did not find anything useful. My JS does not use any console calls, and I tried using cache: false in my ajax calls, but that did not work.

The template markup that the JS is targeting:

```
@using (Html.BeginBeforeBodyClosePlaceHolder())
{
    <script id="gridItemTemplate" type="text/html">
        <div class="content-block__one-third">
            <div class="add-display-block centered-text add-top-margin add-bottom-margin">
                <a href="${ItemUrl}" class="link-undressed">
                    <picture>
                        <img class="flex" srcset="${ThumbnailPhotoUrl}?quality=80&width=500&mode=crop&format=jpg 1x, ${ThumbnailPhotoUrl}?quality=80&width=500&mode=crop&format=jpg 2x" alt="image"/>
                    </picture>
                </a>
                <a href="${ItemUrl}" class="link-undressed">
                    <h3 class="uppercase no-bottom-margin">${ThumbnailItemTitle}</h3>
                </a>
                {{if $(ThumbnailItemDescription) != null && $(ThumbnailItemDescription) != ""}}
                    <p class="no-top-padding no-top-margin sm-text">${ThumbnailItemDescription}</p>
                {{/if}}
                {{if $(ThumbnailItemDate) != null && $(ThumbnailItemDate) != ""}}
                    <p class="no-top-padding no-top-margin sm-text">${ThumbnailItemDate}</p>
                {{/if}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>
}
```

The JS:

```
$(function () {
   $('#btnSeeMore').click(function (e) {
    var lastContentBlock = $('#subItemGrid').children('div.content-block__one-third').last();
    var gridItemId = lastContentBlock.siblings('input#GridItemId').last().val();

    // Get the number of content blocks currently within the subItemGrid
    var gridItemCount = $('#subItemGrid').children('div.content-block__one-third').length;

    var anchor = lastContentBlock.find('a');
    if (anchor != null && anchor.length > 0) {
        var ahref = anchor.attr('href');
        var slashIndex = ahref.lastIndexOf('/');
        var itemName = ahref.substring(slashIndex + 1);
        var itemType = "";

        if (ahref.indexOf('recipe') > 0) {
            itemType = "Recipe";
        } else if (ahref.indexOf('news') > 0) {
            itemType = "News Article";
        } else if (ahref.indexOf('event') > 0) {
            itemType = "Event";
        }

        $.get('/api/WFBC/GetNextContentItems', { itemType: itemType, lastItemName: itemName }, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                // Slide the See More button down
                $('#gridItemTemplate').render(data.nextItems).appendTo('div.content-block');
                if (data.endOfItems) {
                    // Disable the See More button
                    $('#btnSeeMore').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            } else {
                // Disable the See More button
                $('#btnSeeMore').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    } else {
        var itemGuid = $('#ItemGuid').val();
        $.get('/api/WFBC/GetNextGridItems', { gridItemId: gridItemId, gridItemCount: gridItemCount, pageItemGuid: itemGuid }, function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                // Slide the See More button down
                $('#gridItemTemplate').render(data.nextItems).appendTo('div#subItemGrid');
                if (data.endOfItems) {
                    // Disable the See More button
                    $('#btnSeeMore').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            } else {
                // Disable the See More button
                $('#btnSeeMore').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

What could be causing IE to not render the images automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by removing the retina specifications (more information on retina [here](http://thenewcode.com/944/Responsive-Images-For-Retina-Using-HTML5s-srcset)) from the `srcset` tag of each image and using `src` instead. If you look at the first `img` tag in the HTML, it has a `1x`, then `2x` - that is retina. By removing `1x` and everything after it, and using `src` instead of `srcset`, I have no problem rendering new images in IE. Example of working markup:

`<img class="flex" src="${ThumbnailPhotoUrl}?quality=80&width=500&mode=crop&format=jpg" alt="image"/>`

Taken from my link - IE does not support `srcset`, and because I did not have `src` in my markup originally, IE did not like it:

> Browsers that don’t support srcset will fall back to the file
>   specified in src, absent a polyfill.

For more information on `srcset` support across browsers, check out [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset) helpful page.