# Jquery works only after launching developer tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I am trying to put a restriction in my text boxes to enter only numbers, by adding event listener for each text boxes id having a pattern.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOnlyTextBoxes = 'input[id$="NumOnly"]';
  $(numOnlyTextBoxes).each(function() {
    alert(this.id);
    this.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      var val = this.value,
        rx = /[^\d]/g;
      if (rx.test(val)) {
        var pos = this.selectionStart;
        this.value = val.replace(rx, "");
        this.selectionStart = pos;
        this.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<INPUT id="firstNumOnly" TYPE="text" NAME="">
<INPUT id="secondNumOnly" TYPE="text" NAME="">
<INPUT id="thirdNumOnly" TYPE="text" NAME="">
```

I used this addEventListener approach to ensure it is validated in copy paste as well. First alert box is displayed and after that 2 more alerts are not coming. And all Text boxes are working as expected only when i launch IE developer tool.
As specified in this link [Why does JavaScript only work after opening developer tools in IE once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once) , i am not using any console  and also i tried putting `$.ajax({cache: false, ...})` in my code but even then it is not working. Browser: IE11
But a plain HTML or the JS fiddle working

I got error like .addEventListener is not supported, for that reason my onload function has below code as well

```
/* IE11 Fix for SP2010 */ 
                if (typeof(UserAgentInfo) != 'undefined' &amp;&amp; !window.addEventListener) 
                { 
                    UserAgentInfo.strBrowser=1; 
                }
```

Comment: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: I just tried your code in IE10 with no developer tools open, and it worked fine.

Comment: You could've written it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kcd3cde7/4/

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery's methods for defining event listeners, e.g. $(numOnlyTextBoxes).on('input', function...)`?

Comment: just fyi: the regex you specified replaces all parts which are no numbers (e.g. copy "a1b2" and strg+v results in "12". Is this what you intent to do? `/.*[^\d].*/gm` would match all strings (multiline) which do contain non-number values

Comment: @JDB its IE11 browser

Comment: @Barmar, any other way of implementing this. I am expecting function which works on copy paste as well

Comment: @r3bel perfect, i dint notice that "a1b2" was copying as 12. Thanks, i updated regex.

Comment: @Pat Your code works for paste.

Comment: @Barmar, i could not add class to the text boxes and use that in selector, because i need to make change in more places. So can we still use that id for selector? This is not working: https://jsfiddle.net/kcd3cde7/6/

Comment: `$(this.id)` should be either `$(this)` or `$('#' + this.id)`. `$(this)` is generally better. But there's no need for `.each()`, you can use `$(numOnlyTextBoxes).on("input", ...)`