# JavaScript is not working until I click the developer tools in all major browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am passing data to Bootstrap charts from Laravel controller using JQuery. The problem is that the charts does not display. But when I click the developer tools (F12), it displays making it difficult to debug.

Other charts that are not using ajax loads just fine. Here is my code:

```
var Years = new Array();
var Labels = new Array();
var shares = new Array();

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get(url + 'shares/yearly', function (response) {

            response.forEach(function (data) {
                Years.push(data.year);
                Labels.push(data.year);
                shares.push(data.shares);
            });

        });

        var ctxB = document.getElementById("sharesAnnullyChart").getContext('2d');
        var myBarChart = new Chart(ctxB, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {

                labels: Years,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Shares',
                    data: shares,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            optionss: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    })
```

I have tried the answers discussed under this link and it seems there is no console commands in my code: here is the link:
The link is [here.](http://http:/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once)

Any ideas, Please assist me, I have been trying to find a solution now almost a week.

Comment: What browser does this happen to you in? Are you cached with a bad version of the response and you have your dev tools set up to not cache when open? Add error handler to your call.

Comment: `labels: Years` obviously can't work, because you're fetching `Years` asynchronously, so it's not yet defined (or empty) when you do `labels: Years`.

Comment: Years array is already defined outside the loop. I am sorry I didn't show this in my initial code but I have edited it. Data is being fetched from the back end successfully. The issue is the chart doesn't display till I click developer tools.