# Angular - Promise resolves on next change detection cycle

Tags: angular, promise, angular2-changedetection, angular-changedetection

I am calling a function which returns Promise.all.

```
applyFilterToSh = (sheet, name, value)=>{
  return sheet.applyFilterAsync(name, value, tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE);
}

applyFilterToSheets = (name, value) => {
  let sheets = this.getActiveSheet().getWorksheets();
  return Promise.all(sheets.map((sheet)=>{
    return this.applyFilterToSh(sheet, name, value);
  }))
}

setDefaultFilters(){
this.applyFilterToSheets(filterValues[0].name, filterValues[0].values[0].formattedValue).then((s)=>{
        this.gFilters.setIsDashboardLoading(false);
        this.gFilters.setAllFilters(this.currentFiltersList);
      })
}
```

The success callback only fires if I open the browser console or if I close it.`

Comment: Do you still have console.log() statements ( or other console methods, like console.trace ) inside the code? If so, does removing those lines fix the issue? If so, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742781/why-does-javascript-only-work-after-opening-developer-tools-in-ie-once and the comments given there. You might have angular caching issues, you might be using a browser still affected by this bug, etc...

Comment: Please provide the code where you call the function, etc.

Comment: Modified my code - added the code where I make a call to applyFilterToSheets  function

Comment: At first sight, it looks like correct code. Maybe something wrong in your `applyFilterAsync` method

Comment: I noticed , it takes long time to get to the success callback. But the moment I open the console, it gets fired. Is this anything specific to Angular?